# How to sum two curves with different array binning

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have two dataframes A and B. In both, the first column is the frequency and the second column is the luminosity. A and B have different lengths, the frequencies start and end are different, as well as the values of each frequency (different binning).

I want an array where the first column is the frequency of A and the second column is the sum of the luminosities of array A and array B in a given frequency range.

How can I do it?

For example

```
A={'frequency': [1,2,3,4],
    'luminosity': [20,22,24,26]}

B={'frequency': [1.2,1.4,2.1,2.3,2.7,3.4],
    'luminosity': [21.3,21.2,22.2,22.3,22.4,23.3]}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=A)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=B)
```

I would like something like

```
df = {'frequency': [1,2,3,4],
    'luminosity': [20+21.3+21.2,22+22.2+22.3,24+22.4+23.3,26]}
```

where I sum all the luminosities (from A and B) with frequency between `df.loc['frequency']-0.5` and `df.loc['frequency']+0.5`

Comment: If you can provide some sample data, as well as what the output should be it would be most helpful.  Also post any code you've tried so far.

Comment: I agree with @Chris, maybe use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html as a starting point to try.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the A frequency values are always spaced with exactly 1? You imply this with your range `[df.loc['frequency']-0.5, df.loc['frequency']+0.5]`.

Answer (score 0):

I will show how to aggregate `df2` on the frequencies from `df1`. Should be easy to extend to multiple dfs

You can use `pd.cut` and a `groupby`.

We start by defining the bins for frequency based on `df1`:

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['frequency']-0.5,df1['frequency']+0.5)
bins
```

output:

```
IntervalIndex([(0.5, 1.5], (1.5, 2.5], (2.5, 3.5], (3.5, 4.5]],
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

Now we groupby on the pd.cut over these bins and apply the sum

```
df2.groupby(pd.cut(df2['frequency'], bins))['luminosity'].sum().to_frame()
```

output

```
            luminosity
frequency   
(0.5, 1.5]  42.5
(1.5, 2.5]  44.5
(2.5, 3.5]  45.7
(3.5, 4.5]  0.0
```

Comment: The last bin should be 26.

Comment: as I mentioned I am not adding df1 and df2 to df; I am just binning df2 on df1. this is reasonably easy to extend to bin df1 and df2 on df and then add them together